# Unable to Run Tensorflow/Keras with GPU 3090

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a GPU Nvidea 3090
I use keras/tensorflow 2.10
Python versión is 3.10
cude version is 11.7
anda i tray cudnn 8.4, 8.4.1 and 8.9.1

but when i use tensorflow y get this error:

023-06-14 11:39:11.363286: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8401

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I don´t have any idea

I use diferent cersion of cuda, keras and cudnn.

I expet, a combination of programs to use cuda

Comment: Hi @Juan Jose, you may need to use specific version of CUDA and cuDNN compatible to installed python version 3.10 and tensorflow 2.10 for GPU support enabled in your system which are `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1`. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) and follow the Hardware/Software requirements given along with step by step instructions mentioned to install the tensorflow with GPU as per your system OS.